# httpclientandroidlib used by android-async-http loopj is slow

Tags: android, performance, apache-httpclient-4.x, loopj, android-async-http

I have an application using [android-async-http](https://github.com/loopj/android-async-http) library by loopj for networking to retrieve JSON.  I am seeing that network requests are slow, taking about 1 second each.  The same calls from the iOS app take around 250ms, so I know that the problem is not on the server, it is in the client.  Putting log messages in my code and the android-async-http library to see where it is slow, I am seeing that the time is being taken up by a call to client.execute(request, context) within the android-async-http library.

I am aware that google no longer recommends using the apache http client, however android-async-http is using it.

I have tried using [httpclienandroidlib-1.1.2](https://code.google.com/p/httpclientandroidlib/), which fixed some other bugs that I was seeing, but did not improve the performance.

I have ensured that keep-alive is turned on and working.  This improves subsequent requests to about 750ms.  The first request is still slow, and our iOS app is even faster on subsequent requests.

Has anybody else seen the networking on Android being slow?  If so, what did you do to improve it?

Answer (score 0):

I use the same lib in your link w/ android.

I use a threadpool, 5 avail threads for each domain, handlers for async-like http speed and have a fast server.

loop-j or pure async-http may not be necessary. In your case it sure is not fast.

I use android 4.2 on a current device on WIFI and can saturate the full available bandwidth as a single wifi user with scores of  http requests...

I get 20 - 30 req. per second thruput on uploads where each upload is 80k of binary data.

http://pastebin.com/v4EDq6mr

scroll the pastbin to line 57 for details.